# Clearing column data

Tags: vba, excel

Im trying to figure how to clear data from A2 to end of column.
In theory mine code is working, but only if the selector is somewhere outside the range to clear.

```
Sub ClearData()

Worksheets("aa").Range("a2", 
Worksheets("aa").Range("a2").End(xlDown)).ClearContents

End Sub
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure this must have been asked and answered a million times before. I don't know what you mean by 'the selector'.

```
Sub ClearData()

With Worksheets("aa")
    .Range("a2", .Range("a" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).ClearContents
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: The "Black" frame around cells.
With your code is same as with mine, this selector blocking clearing

Comment: I don't know what you mean. That shouldn't make any difference - neither your code nor mine selects anything.

Answer (score 1):

Do't be concerned with the actual end of data:

```
Sub ClearData()

    With Worksheets("aa")
        .Range("A2:A" & Rows.Count).ClearContents
    End With

End Sub
```

will work just fine.

Comment: I know it doesn't make much difference, but why clear a million cells when you can clear a hundred?

Comment: @SJR  I have not been able to detect any difference in timing

Comment: I wondered if there was some reason for suggesting this, as I don't see how it would solve the OP's problem (not that he explained it properly).

Comment: @SJR  I assume that he wanted to clear all cells from **A2** through the bottom of data.  That means spending extra effort *finding* the bottom of data.  Because there is no data below the bottom of data, it can't hurt to clear those cells.

Comment: @SJR  In fact, doing `Cells.ClearContents` clears **all** cells in **all** columns !  It also appears to work instantaneously !

Comment: Curiouser and curiouser. You'd think there would be some overhead.

Comment: @SJR  I can't explain it either.